# Xhtml page mapping from ManagedBean

Tags: spring, jsf, managed-bean

Here Is Managed Bean Class

```
        package Controller;

        import java.io.Serializable;

        import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
        import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
        import Model.Employee;

         @ManagedBean(name="employeeController")
        @SessionScoped
        public class Employeecontroller implements Serializable{

        public String show(){
          System.out.println("hello");

             return "Login";

            }

           }
```

Here Is web.xml file

```
                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
                      <display-name>Secondproject</display-name>
                      <welcome-file-list>
                        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
                        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
                        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
                        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
                        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
                        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
                      </welcome-file-list>
                      <servlet>
                        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
                        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
                        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
                      </servlet>
                      <servlet-mapping>
                        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
                         <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern> 
                        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
                      </servlet-mapping>
                      <context-param>
                        <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
                        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
                        <param-value>client</param-value>
                      </context-param>
                      <context-param>
                        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
                        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
                      </context-param>
                      <listener>
                        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
                      </listener>
                       <welcome-file-list>  
                       <welcome-file>homepage.xhtml</welcome-file>  
                      </welcome-file-list>  
                    </web-app>
```

Here id home.xhtml page

```
                    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                        xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
                        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                        xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
                        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

                    <h:head></h:head>
                    <body>
                        <rich:panel>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                            Write your own custom rich components with built-in AJAX support
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="Panel Body" />
                            <h:form>
                                <h:commandButton action="#{employeeController.show()}" value="Login" />
                            </h:form>

                        </rich:panel>
                    </body>
                    </html>
```

Here is the code for mapping xhtml page from ManagedBean. 
  I just want when the button is clicked then the login page will show....But when the button is clicked there is only home.xhtml page reloading...Login page is not loading....

Comment: the same page reloads, if `NavigationHandler` can't find the view with name returned from action method. `show()` is returning "Login", so you should have `Login.xhtml` not `login.xhtml`.

Answer (score 0):

The selection of the next view depends on the value of the action attribute of the UICommand components. If the navigation handler finds a navigation rule for this page with this outcome, the next view will be the  element content. If there is no any rule like this it looks for a page with the value (or it appended with ".xhtml" file extension).

The variations:

1., Direct view definition:

```
<h:commandButton action="next_page_name"/>
```

It must be a full qualified name (page names + file name), but the xhtml could be omitted.

2., Indirect view definition:
In this case the action value is contains a bean method invocation:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{myBean.methodName}"/>
```

This method should be a function without any parameter and passes back a String value. This result will be the income for the navigation handler. It could return a page name or a navigation rule.

Now let us see your problem. If the name of your current view is id_home.xhml and you want to navigate to the login.xhtml page (both are in the x package):

1., Direct view definition. Return value "x/login" or "x/login.xhtml" from the show() method:

```
public String show()
{
  //...
  return "x/login";
}
```

2., Indirect view definition. Define a page navigation rule in the faces-config.xml like this:

```
<navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>/x/id_home.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
      <from-outcome>go_to_login</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>x/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
  </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

In this case myBean.methodName passes back the content of the form-outcome element:

```
public String show()
{
  //...
  return "go_to_login";
}
```

Comment: If it worked to you, please accept an vote it up, please